# SQL Expression (select max value from one table, use that to offset value inserted from another table)

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have tables called **Actors** and **Directors**. both of those have their **ID** as Autonumber. I move them to my new database and add them into table called **Persons**. First I insert **Actors**, then **Directors**, so if **Directors** ID was 00001 it is now 00001+max value of the column **ID** from **Actors** table since it is added to the end of the list. (so if last actor was 00050 now first director is 00050+00001=00051 and so on)

Now I have other tables that hold the connections from **Movies** to multiple **Actors** and **Directors**

What I need is an SQL expression to figure out how to do something like this:

INSERT INTO Movies_Actors (Movies_Actors.movie_id,Movies_Actors.person_id) IN 'C:'NewDB.accdb'
SELECT movie_id,actor_id
FROM Movies_Actors;

and then

INSERT INTO Movies_Directors (**Movies_Actors.movie_id,Movies_Actors.person_id**) IN 'C:'NewDB.accdb'
SELECT movie_id,**director_id+maxValue(Actors.id)**
FROM Movies_Actors;

in order to keep my connections healthy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to make an extra query which would save the maxValue of Actors and then use that value in the main query as in

<...>

,director_id+maxValueQuery.MaxV
From Movies_Actors,maxValueQuery;